# read_fwf not working while unzipping files

Tags: r, readr

I want to read in several fixed width format txt files into R but I first need to unzip them.

Since they are very large files I want to use `read_fwf` from the `readr` package because it's very fast.

When I do:

`read_fwf(unz(zipfileName, fileName), fwf_widths(colWidths, col_names = colNames))`

I get this error `Error in isOpen(con) : invalid connection`

However when I do:

`read.table(unz(zipfileName, fileName))` without specfiying widths it reads into `R` just fine. Any thoughts as to why this isn't working with `read_fwf` ?

I am having trouble making a reproducible example. Here is what I got:

```
df <- data.frame(
  rnorm(100),
  rnorm(100)
)

write.table(df, "data.txt", row.names=F, col.names = F)
zip(zipfile = "data.zip", files = "data.txt")
colWidths <- rep(2, 100)
colNames <- c("thing1","thing2")
zipfileName <- "data.zip"
fileName <- "data.csv"
```

Comment: I only see one column. I also do not see that you defined 'zipfileName'

Comment: @42- made edits to make example match the problem.

Comment: Read `?unz` more carefully. In particular: `"The 'description' is the full path to the zip file, with ‘.zip’ extension if required."`

Comment: In my actual code I have the full path to the zip file specified as `description` and the .txt file within the zip as `filename`. The problem is unzipping works fine when a base R function is wrapped around the `unz` function but when  use `read_fwf` I get an error.

Comment: Exactly. So as the doctor (me) says: "If it always hurts when you twist my arm this way,.... then stop doing that".  (At least until you send a bug report to Hadley.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had trouble getting read_fwf to read zip files when passing an `unz`-ed file to it but then reading the `?read_fwf` page I see that zipped files are promised to be handled automagically. You didn't make a file that was a valid fwf as an example, since neither of the columns had constant positions but that is apparent with the output:

```
read_fwf(file="~/data.zip", fwf_widths(widths=rep(16,2) ,col_names = colNames) )
Warning: 1 parsing failure.
row    col expected actual
  3 thing2 16 chars     14
# A tibble: 100 x 2
             thing1               thing2
              <chr>                <chr>
1  1.37170820802141    -0.58354018425322
2  0.03608988699566 7 -0.402708262870141
3  1.02963272114 -1       .0644333112294
4  0.73546166509663  8 0.607941664550652
5  -1.5285547658079   -0.319983522035755
6  -1.4673290956901    0.523579231857175
7  0.24946312418273 9 -0.574046655188405
8  0.58126541455159 5 -0.406516495600345
9   1.5074477698981   -0.496512994239183
10 -2.2999905645658 8 -0.662667854341041
# ... with 90 more rows
```

The error you were getting was from the `unz` function because it expects a full path to a zip extension file (and apparently won't accept an implicit working directory location) as the "description" argument. It's second argument is the name of the compressed file inside the zip file. I think it returns a connection, but not of a type that read_fwf is able to process. Doing parsing by hand I see that the errors both of us got was from this section of code in `read_connection`:

```
> readr:::read_connection
function (con) 
{
    stopifnot(is.connection(con))
    if (!isOpen(con)) {
        open(con, "rb")
        on.exit(close(con), add = TRUE)
    }
    read_connection_(con)
}
<environment: namespace:readr>
```

You didn't give `unz` a valid "description" argument, and even if we did the effort to open with `open(con, "rb")` fails because of the lack of standardization in  arguments in the various file handling functions.

Comment: Fortunately in my case each zip file only contains the one file I want to read into R. I'm curious about how `read_fwf` would handle a zip file with several files.

Comment: When I gave it a zip file with two items it picked the first one. (I would have expanded the zip file to a full directory and then worked with that if I wanted the second or later file.)

Comment: Thanks for checking this. This is good to know and I think has some implications about how `read_fwf` should handle zip files.